# EF Core Configuring Complex Types

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm learning C# at the moment with .NET Core and EF Core for working with database.

Now I'm at the point where I got stuck configuring my entities.

I have written the following classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    #region Properties
    public Guid CustomerID { get; set; }
    ...
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public Customer()
    {
        Address = new Address();
    }
}

public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        //Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(c => c.CustomerID);

        //Complex Types
        builder.OwnsOne<Address>("Address");
    }
}

public class Employee
{
    #region Properties
    public Guid EmployeeID { get; set; }
    ...
    public Address Address { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public Employee()
    {
        Address = new Address();
    }
}

public class EmployeeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> builder)
    {
        //Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(c => c.EmployeeID);

        //Complex Types
        builder.OwnsOne<Address>("Address");
    }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public State State { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

I need to configure `Address` class with Fluent API that `Address.Street` is for `Customer` and `Employee` MaxLength = 50?

Is it possible to configure it for both at the same time? Or do I need to configure it for each entity?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When I understand you correctly you want to have different configurations for `Address` depending off the owned type? Yes this is possible, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#mapping-owned-types-with-table-splitting

Or do you wanna have a shared configuration?

Comment: I want to configure for example Street has MaxLength(50) and it will be written once for Customer and Employee at the same time.

Comment: That's what I answered. *Is it possible to configure it for both at the same time?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valid answer of **@Gert Arnold** demonstrates, how to accomplish what you want for all of your target entities in a centralized way.

In case you want to keep the information in your configuration classes, then you can define it there instead (but it could be a bit more redundant, depending on the case):

```cs
public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        //Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(c => c.CustomerID);

        //Complex Types
        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Address)
            .Property(e => e.Street)
            .HasMaxLength(50);
    }
}

public class EmployeeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Employee>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Employee> builder)
    {
        //Primary Key
        builder.HasKey(c => c.EmployeeID);

        //Complex Types
        builder.OwnsOne(e => e.Address)
            .Property(e => e.Street)
            .HasMaxLength(42); // or 50 if you want
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Until the current stable version of Entity Framework Core (3.1.6) this is not possible.
Quote:

> Instances of owned entity types cannot be shared by multiple owners
> (this is a well-known scenario for value objects that cannot be
> implemented using owned entity types)

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#current-shortcomings.

Your only option here would be to make `Address` an Entity itself with its own table.
Then you would have an many-to-one relation from `Customer` /  `Employee` (many) to `Address` (one).

For this you would have to extend your `Address` with a primary key and `Customer` and `Employee` with a foreign key each referencing `Address`. Then as you would do normally you can create a TypeConfiguration with your validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

You can set all kinds of attributes of model types at once because they're easily accessible by `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()`. Setting max length of owned type properties can be done like so:

```cs
var ownedAddresses = modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
    .Where(t => t.IsOwned() && t.ClrType == typeof(Address))
    .ToList();
foreach (var address in ownedAddresses)
{
    address.FindProperty("Street").SetMaxLength(50);
}
```

...after the owned types have been registered to the model builder, i.e. after you added the type configurations.

Of course, the `Where(t => t.IsOwned()` predicate is redundant here. It's just to show another way to find owned types.

Comment: Downvoter, please elaborate? This perfectly answers the question "both at the same time".